# How to optimize this linq query to reduce the loops?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, refactoring

I want to optimize this query and reduce the number of loops if possible. Atleast the one where i have to select all the client id first for iteration purpose.
 any help appreciated.

```
public DataTable convertCollectionExpectedToDatatable(List<Invoice> lst)
        {
            DataTable dtcollection = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dtcollection.Columns.Add("ClientId", typeof(string));
                dtcollection.Columns.Add("customerName", typeof(string));
                dtcollection.Columns.Add("BalAmnt1", typeof(string));
                dtcollection.Columns.Add("BalAmnt2", typeof(string));
                dtcollection.Columns.Add("BalAmnt3", typeof(string));
                dtcollection.Columns.Add("totalAmt", typeof(string));

                DateTime promiseDate1 = DateTime.Today;
                DateTime promiseDate2 = promiseDate1.AddDays(1);
                DateTime promiseDate3 = promiseDate2.AddDays(1);

                var select = (from l in lst select l.ClientId).Distinct();
                List<long> lstInv = select.ToList<long>();

                DataRow dr;
                foreach (long inv in lstInv)
                {
                    decimal BalAmnt1 = lst.Where(Invoice => Invoice.ExpDt ==  
promiseDate1 && Invoice.ClientId == inv).Select(Invoice => Invoice.BalAmnt).Sum();
                    decimal BalAmnt2 = lst.Where(Invoice => Invoice.ExpDt == 
promiseDate2 && Invoice.ClientId == inv).Select(Invoice => Invoice.BalAmnt).Sum();
                    decimal BalAmnt3 = lst.Where(Invoice => Invoice.ExpDt == 
promiseDate3 && Invoice.ClientId == inv).Select(Invoice => Invoice.BalAmnt).Sum();

                    var clientName = (from l in lst where l.ClientId == inv select 
l.Client.Name).FirstOrDefault();

                    dr = dtcollection.NewRow();
                    dr["ClientId"] = inv.ToString();
                    dr["customerName"] = clientName.ToString();
                    dr["BalAmnt1"] = string.Format("{0:n2}", BalAmnt1);
                    dr["BalAmnt2"] = string.Format("{0:n2}", BalAmnt2);
                    dr["BalAmnt3"] = string.Format("{0:n2}", BalAmnt3);
                    dr["totalAmt"] = string.Format("{0:n2}", BalAmnt1 + BalAmnt2 + 
BalAmnt3);

                    dtcollection.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
```

Comment: At least this line `List<long> lstInv = select.ToList<long>();` is completely unnecessary. You can iterate over distinct ids without creating list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group invoices by `ClientId` and calculate all sums with this query:

```
from invoice in lst
group invoice by invoice.ClientId into g
select new {
   BalAmnt1 = g.Where(i => i.ExpDt == promiseDate1).Sum(i => i.BalAmnt),
   BalAmnt2 = g.Where(i => i.ExpDt == promiseDate2).Sum(i => i.BalAmnt),
   BalAmnt3 = g.Where(i => i.ExpDt == promiseDate3).Sum(i => i.BalAmnt)
}
```

Also consider better naming. What name `lst` will tell to people who will read your code. If this is a list of invoices, then name it `invoices`. Same with promiseDates - `today` and `tomorrow` will better describe what dates stored in variables:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
// don't know how to name dayAfterTomorrow
// suppose it has some business-specific name in your case
```

Also you can extract duplicated code into separate method:

```
public static decimal CalculateBalanceOn(
    this IEnumerable<Invoice> invoices, DateTime date)
{
    return invoices.Where(i => i.ExpDt == date).Sum(i => i.BalAmnt);
}
```

With all above query will look like:

```
from invoice in invoices
group invoice by invoice.ClientId into g
select new {
   BalanceToday = g.CalculateBalanceOn(today),
   BalanceTomorrow = g.CalculateBalanceOn(tomorrow),
   BalanceAfterTomorrow = g.CalculateBalanceOn(dayAfterTomorrow)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the instant reply. I was wondering how would i be able to populate a data table with the output of this query as i am storing it in a List<Object>.

The solution works btw in terms of optimization.. just wanted to let u kn ow this was a further concern...

Comment: @JayantShelke don't store it in list. This query produces strongly typed anonymous objects. Just iterate over them, e.g. `foreach(var item in query) { dr["BalAmnt1"] = String.Format("{0:n2}", item.BalAmnt1); ... }`